# FFMPEG picture in picture

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I try to put a portion of video in a video at a certain time.

Se here's my command:

```
./ffmpeg-3.0-32bit-static/ffmpeg \
-y \
-i main.mp4 \
-itsoffset -10 \
-i overlay.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"[1:a] atrim=5:20 [1:a1]; \
[1:a1] adelay=5000|5000 [1:a2]; \
[0:a][1:a2] amix [outa]; \
[1:v] scale=120:-1 [1:v1]; \
[0:v][1:v1] overlay=x=25:y=25:enable='between(t,5,20)'[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" \
-map "[outa]" \
-c:a aac \
-c:v libx264 \
-vb 1000k \
-r 24 \
-strict -2 \
output.mp4
```

But I've got "Buffer queue overflow, dropping" messages which, I think, makes my overlay.mp4 a little jerky on the output.mp4 :

```
[Parsed_overlay_4 @ 0xc29d9c0] [framesync @ 0xc29da84] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.
    Last message repeated 50 times
[Parsed_overlay_4 @ 0xc29d9c0] [framesync @ 0xc29da84] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.0.927x
[Parsed_overlay_4 @ 0xc29d9c0] [framesync @ 0xc29da84] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.=2.72x
    Last message repeated 33 times
[Parsed_overlay_4 @ 0xc29d9c0] [framesync @ 0xc29da84] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.=2.72x
    Last message repeated 14 times
[Parsed_overlay_4 @ 0xc29d9c0] [framesync @ 0xc29da84] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.=2.97x
    Last message repeated 13 times
[Parsed_overlay_4 @ 0xc29d9c0] [framesync @ 0xc29da84] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.=3.16x
    Last message repeated 35 times
[Parsed_overlay_4 @ 0xc29d9c0] [framesync @ 0xc29da84] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.=3.35x
    Last message repeated 45 times
[Parsed_overlay_4 @ 0xc29d9c0] [framesync @ 0xc29da84] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.=3.46x
    Last message repeated 5 times
```

Any idea why?

EDIT: Forgot to say I've got the last version of ffmpeg => 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ffmpeg -y -i main.mp4 -i overlay.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"[1:a] atrim=15:30,adelay=5000|5000 [a1]; \
[0:a][a1] amix [outa]; \
[1:v] scale=120:-1,setpts=PTS-(10/TB) [1v]; \
[0:v][1v] overlay=x=25:y=25:enable='between(t,5,20)'[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" \
-c:a aac -c:v libx264 \
-b:v 1000k \
-r 24 \
output.mp4
```

In case your overlay is longer than your main input, use `amix=duration=shortest` and `overlay=x=25:y=25:enable='between(t,5,20):shortest=1`

For the same video,

```
ffmpeg -y -i main.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:a]asplit[a1][a2];
 [a2] volume=0:enable='between(t\,0,15)',asetpts=PTS-(10/TB) [a3]; \
 [a1][a3] amix [outa]; \
 [0:v]fps=24,split[v1][v2];
 [v2] scale=120:-1,setpts=PTS-(10/TB) [v3]; \
 [v1][v3] overlay=x=25:y=25:enable='between(t,5,20)'[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" \
-c:a aac -c:v libx264 \
-b:v 1000k \
output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mulvya. Unfortunately, I still got the same issue "Buffer queue overflow, dropping." even with your command. (and with the 'shortest' option.) Your command is much clearer though!

Comment: what's the framerates of the two inputs?

Comment: They're both 24.000 fps. main.mp4 and overlay.mp4 are actually the same video. (which is of course... bunny!)

Comment: Still the same issue. =) Do you have this issue as well?

Comment: Do the video and audio filter separately. Then stream-copy those outputs in the merged file..

Comment: Yup, I already tried that actually and that worked well. But it needs 3 commands though... I really want to use only 1 command. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Sounds like the variation in timestamps is the issue. Try the edited 2nd command for one final assay.